# How to change the range of adf paginated table dynamically

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a adf-table having scroll policy as "page". Every page has 25 rows. I need to go to any page say from 1 to 5 dynamically. How to do it in adf. My original requirement is go to first page on some button click.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to build a test page to verify this works, but I would put a method like this (see below) in my `ViewObjectImpl` class.

It basically calculate the row number you want to jump to, then it finds the row at that position and makes that the current row and also puts it at the top of the current range.

```
/**
 * Navigates the ViewObject to the top of the specified page
 * @param pageNumber a 1-based page number to navigate to
 */
public void setPage(int pageNumber) {
    final int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 25;
    // rows in range are zero-based, so page 1 is rows 0..24, page 2 is rows 25..49, etc.
    int rowNumberForTopOfPage = (pageNumber-1) * ROWS_PER_PAGE;
    Row rowAtTopOfPage = null;
    // Iterate through the rows to find the row at the top of the desired page
    RowSetIterator it = this.createRowSetIterator(null);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Row r = (Row) it.next();
        if ( it.getCurrentRowIndex() == rowNumberForTopOfPage ) {
            rowAtTopOfPage = r;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( rowAtTopOfPage != null ) {
        this.setCurrentRow(rowAtTopOfPage);
        this.scrollRangeTo(rowAtTopOfPage, 0);
    }
}
```

Then, call it to set the page to what you want.  Or, expose it to the client and call it from a bean (but make sure you add the appropriate UI components as via `AdfFacesContext.addPartialTarget` to ensure the UI components get updated to reflect that the view object's current row has been changed.